# Inno Setup "deleteafterinstall" flag: What happens if file is locked?

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using the `deleteafterinstall` flag for some temporary files, but if they are still locked by a process at the time Inno Setup installer is finishing, will they be scheduled to be deleted later?

The documentation doesn't mention what happens in that case:

> deleteafterinstall
>
> Instructs Setup to install the file as usual, but
> then delete it once the installation is completed (or aborted). This
> can be useful for extracting temporary data needed by a program
> executed in the script's [Run] section.
>
> This flag will not cause existing files that weren't replaced during
> installation to be deleted.
>
> This flag cannot be combined with the isreadme, regserver, regtypelib,
> restartreplace, sharedfile, or uninsneveruninstall flags.

Comment: Did you try it out? InnoSetups help doesn't detail this, so I guess the usual Inno behaviour will kick in and an error message will be shown to the user. For example for resetreplace ( http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection ), they can restart the computer, and detail this, so I guess they would detail a scheduled deletion in the manual too. But testing this out should be easy to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how much deep explanation you expect for the answer, but the best for this I think is to jump into the source code. So, all the files having the [`deleteafterinstall`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=deleteafterinstall) flag specified are added to the [`DeleteFilesAfterInstallList`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/Main.pas#L171) collection, which is iterated when the setup is being deinitialized. At that time, the collection is [`iterated file by file`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/Main.pas#L3319) and for each file from that collection is called the [`DeleteFileRedir`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/RedirFunc.pas#L227) function, which optionally disables WOW64 redirection (not important for this case) and calls the Windows API function [`DeleteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which doesn't perform delayed deletion.

Comment: Yep, I just tested it, there was no error message box, and the files were not deleted after rebooting.

Comment: I'm a little bit surprised. I was hoping for `MoveFileEx` with the `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT`, or a call of a build-in function for delayed deletion. Well, either you'll need to be careful and wait until the file handle is released or you may try ask for a feature request on the [`product forum`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/newsgroups.php).